# Use of redux store in feature module

Tags: angular, redux

Is it good practice to use `redux store` for accessing and updating the data in a component of feature module or i should use `@Input` and `@Output` data binding property for providing the data to feature module component.

Answer (score 2):

You should use redux store,because:
If the components are siblings or parent-child in relation, you can use @input and @output but what if they are not then you'll have to use redux store. 
That's why it is preferred to use redux store for updating the data of the component.

Comment: But if I am getting that data from `redux store` to parent component and pass that data to the component of the feature module by  `@Input and @Output` data binding property.so tell which approach is good this one or you mention .

Comment: every component is in child-parent relation with the store,so you can directly send data from the store to the component.Store is connected to every component as it is made global for the application.

Comment: so,I would recommend the approach that I mentioned above.

Comment: if this answer somewhat helps you ,kindly up vote and accept the answer.

Comment: Yes this also an approach but not a scalable approach because sometimes we create a feature module by keeping a thing in mind that we can use it somewhere else I mean in another project so if i use `redux` store then i have to specify the actions and state for accessing and updating the store . so you cannot able to use that in another project so try to do this using `@Input` and `@Output` data binding .

Comment: you can use this approach only if the components are child-parent or siblings in relation.If other than this you'll have to use services or redux store.These are the only two options known to me,if you find any other way kindly guide me also.